# Sed with variables and line number restrictions

Tags: sed

I have the following file:

```
<CamcorderProfiles cameraId="0">

    <EncoderProfile quality="720p" fileFormat="mp4" duration="30">
        <Video codec="h264"
               bitRate="8000000"
               width="1280"
               height="720"
               frameRate="30" />
        <Audio codec="aac"
               bitRate="96000"
               sampleRate="48000"
               channels="1" />
    </EncoderProfile>

    <EncoderProfile quality="1080p" fileFormat="mp4" duration="30">
        <Video codec="h264"
               bitRate="12000000"
               width="1920"
               height="1080"
               frameRate="30" />
        <Audio codec="aac"
               bitRate="96000"
               sampleRate="48000"
               channels="1" />
    </EncoderProfile>

</CamcorderProfiles>

<CamcorderProfiles cameraId="1">

    <EncoderProfile quality="720p" fileFormat="mp4" duration="30">
        <Video codec="h264"
               bitRate="8000000"
               width="1280"
               height="720"
               frameRate="30" />
        <Audio codec="aac"
               bitRate="96000"
               sampleRate="48000"
               channels="1" />
    </EncoderProfile>

    <EncoderProfile quality="1080p" fileFormat="mp4" duration="30">
        <Video codec="h264"
               bitRate="12000000"
               width="1920"
               height="1080"
               frameRate="30" />
        <Audio codec="aac"
               bitRate="96000"
               sampleRate="48000"
               channels="1" />
    </EncoderProfile>

</CamcorderProfiles>
```

Here is my code:

```
camerastart=$(sed -n '{/<CamcorderProfiles cameraId="0">/=}' $file)
cameraend=$(sed -n $camerastart',$ {/<\/CamcorderProfiles>/=}' $file)

camera1080pstart=$(sed -n $camerastart','$cameraend' {/<EncoderProfile quality="1080p" fileFormat="mp4" duration="30">/=}' $file)
```

When I print the variables, I get the correct line numbers on all but camera1080p_start, which comes up blank.

```
camerastart = 3
cameraend = 29
camera1080pstart =
```

If I change up the first line of the code to `cameraId="1"`, then I do get proper results for that case.

```
camerastart = 31
cameraend = 57
camera1080pstart = 45
```

If I change the code so the first two variables are hardcoded in, I do get the proper output of `17` camera1080pstart.

```
camerastart="3"
cameraend="29"

camera1080pstart=$(sed -n $camerastart','$cameraend' {/<EncoderProfile quality="1080p" fileFormat="mp4" duration="30">/=}' $file)
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Yes, you are using the wrong tool. sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for any other text processing task you should use awk.

Comment: Tel us what you are trying to do and post some expected output that matches your sample input and someone will show you the right way to do it.

Comment: What I am after is editing specific lines of the xml file. For example, change the bitRate="12000000" line within the EncoderProfile quality="1080p" tag and within the cameraId="0" tag to something else. Somehow I need to drill down multiple layers of tags so I am changing the line within the correct tags.

Comment: I posted a small awk script to get you started but you'd need to tell us a in what way you want to change the line you find and provide other info to go further.

Answer (score 1):

Change the second command to:

```
cameraend=$(sed -n $camerastart',$ {/<\/CamcorderProfiles>/=}' $file | head -1)
```

because it returns multiple line numbers. However, this might not be the best way to tackle this particular problem.

Comment: You might be on to something. What does that do? Only return the first instance?

Comment: yes, `head -1` returns the first line of its input, so you get the first instance only

Comment: also if you are trying to iterate all instances you can use `grep -c` and `head`.

Comment: You sir are a genius. That did the trick! I'm thinking it would probably be best to put `head -1` on all of them, just in case multiple instances exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that will find and print the line you want to change:

$ cat tst.awk

```
BEGIN{ FS = "\"" }
/<CamcorderProfiles cameraId=/ { cameraId = $2 }
/<EncoderProfile quality=/     { quality  = $2 }
/bitRate="12000000"/ {
   if ( (cameraId == "0") && (quality == "1080p") ) {
      print NR, "this is the line I want to change:"
      print
   }
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
17 this is the line I want to change:
               bitRate="12000000"
```

If you need to be able to invoke it with different cameraId and/or quality and/or any other values, that's a trivial tweak.

If you tell us in what way you want to change the line the script finds, that's trivial too.

EDIT: updated script based on OPs comments below.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS = "\"" }
/<CamcorderProfiles cameraId=/ { cameraId = $2 }
/<EncoderProfile quality=/     { quality  = $2 }
/bitRate="12000000"/ {
   if ( (cameraId == "0") && (quality == "1080p") ) {
      sub(/12000000/,"20000000")
   }
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file > tmpfile

$ diff file tmpfile
17c17
<                bitRate="12000000"
---
>                bitRate="20000000"
```

If you want to update the original file, just run it as:

```
awk -f tst.awk file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

Comment: The reason I was trying to get line 17 in a variable is so I could run something like `sed -i '17 s/12000000/20000000/' file` on that line. Could I perform this right within your script?

Comment: Of course, but you don't need to get the line number when you're already processing the target line. I'll update the script now to change 12000000 to 20000000.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is:

```
camerastart=$(sed -n '{/<CamcorderProfiles cameraId="0">/=}' $file | head -1)
cameraend=$(sed -n $camerastart',$ {/<\/CamcorderProfiles>/=}' $file | head -1)

camera1080pstart=$(sed -n $camerastart','$cameraend' {/<EncoderProfile quality="1080p" fileFormat="mp4" duration="30">/=}' $file | head -1)
```